# Prove $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{a_n^2} $ converges where $a_n$ is the increasing sencquence of all the positive roots of the equation $\tan x = x$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

Let $a_n$ be a increasing sequence of all the positive roots of the equation $\tan x = x$.

I want to prove the series converges:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{a_n^2} $$

It doesn't looks like there is some pattern between $a_n$ terms, So I was not able to express $a_n$ as a formula.
Finding upper bound for $a_n$ didn't worked either.

Any hints will be appreciated.

Comment: Notice that $a_n>n\pi$.

Comment: Notice that : $$a_n > - \dfrac{\pi}{2} + n \pi$$

Comment: @user: an upper bound proves nothing.

Comment: @BobbyLaspy ok, i will try to take it from here with induction.

Comment: @MStudent: you won't succeed with induction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the function function $\tan x-x$ is growing in the intervals $\left(\dfrac{2n-1}{2}\pi,\dfrac{2n+1}{2}\pi\right)$ and negative at $n\pi$, there is at most one root per interval and $a_n>n\pi$. This is enough to conclude convergence. (Hint: Basel series.)